# How to share functional enumeration between applications?

Tags: enums

Currently I have 2 applications sharing one database. As I am trying to follow the DRY principle I moved a few enumerations in the database. 
But now I'm facing one that is used for business code.
e.g. my enum is like { Open, Active, Pending, Pending for approval, Closed, Deleted, ....}

In the database I set to them an ID and a few parameters (like selected on default) and the display name of the enumeration
However in my code I have tons of hardcoded check values: if enum = 4 then do that accross the 2 applications.

I don't see myself adding on column for each state i have for the enumerations, so where am I supposed to store them ?

I was thinking of a Const file but in that case I'm loosing the display name